# Problema repetir background gradient

Tags: html, css, background

Como posso para fazer um background gradient repetir fora da posição definida para o layout?

Considere a seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Precisava repetir o verde água e a cor laranja, que também são gradientes.

EDIT:

Exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/srCN7/

Comment: Quais são as dimensões das áreas de *repeat*?

Comment: O problema está aí... não tem dimensões, qualquer resolução tem que repetir.

Comment: Mostre a estrutura do seu HTML, sem isso fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Veja: http://jsfiddle.net/srCN7/

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se eu entendi bem o que você quer, veja se é isso:

**HTML**

```
<div id='externo'>
    <div id='interno'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#externo{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #38899f, #df2929, #e8742a); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #38899f, #df2929, #e8742a); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #38899f, #df2929, #e8742a); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(left, #38899f, #df2929, #e8742a); /* Standard syntax */
    width:800px;
    height:60px;
}
#interno{
    background:#999;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:55px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vNQ6/